# Why DaoMaster does not have a non-abstract OpenHelper class?

Tags: greendao

why the generated code of greendao does not provide a non-abstract OpenHelper class from the DaoMaster? It only provides the DevOpenHelper, which I assumed only for development mode.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Because greenDAO does not handle schema migration yet. DevOpenHelper just drops all tables and recreates them if the schema version increases. For non-critical data this might be OK.